# My function makes a new line in tkinter, not sure why

Tags: python, string, text, tkinter

I am making a tkinter program and for some reason [I have a function binded to control-O] when I use it, it creates a new line. Here is the function:

```
def fileOpen(textView):
    try:
        global currentText
        global currentName
        global currentTempName
        myfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(title='Open a file', mode='r')
        text.delete('1.0', END)
        loadedfile = myfile.read()
        currentText = loadedfile
        currentFile = myfile.name
        currentName = currentFile
        currentName = currentName.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] #get the 'name.ext' part only
        currentName = currentName.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1] #incase you're usin windows
        currentTempName = currentName
        currentFileButton.config(text = currentName)
        myfile.close()
        textView.insert("end", loadedfile)
    except:
        return
```

Here is where it's binded:

```
def ctrlO(arg):
    fileOpen(text)
```

and the actual binding:

```
root.bind("<Control-o>", ctrlO)
```

[I am using a text widget, and binding to it doesn't fix the problem]

To better explain the problem, when I press ctrl+o to open the openfile dialog, it creates a new line, as if I pressed 'Enter', but only at the end of the file. I can provide more code if needed, but those are the only places those are used at.

Thanks

(I realize that function is messy)

Edit: It doesn't really affect the program as I clear the text between openings, but it just is a bit annoying and I'm sure easily fixable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the normal behavior of Control-O in a Text widget; it would happen even if you didn't have your key binding at all.  To override it, you need to `return "break"` in your event handler, to prevent any further propagation of the event.  I'm pretty sure that you'll have to bind directly to the Text widget for this to activate before the built-in behavior.  You may still want a binding on the root widget, so that the command works even if the user never clicked in the text field to give it keyboard focus.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I changed the binding to root, because didnt work with text as you said and the return 'break' worked. Is there a list of all the premade behaviors for bindings? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only complete list of keybindings I could find is at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/text.htm near the bottom - note that this is written for the underlying Tk environment, not the Tkinter wrapper.

Comment: Okay thanks, one last mini question, is it common practice to break every custom binding like that? Or just those situations